# Decay rate and differential cross-section

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering-cross-section, beyond-the-standard-model

If I have a $pp-$beam producing an on-shell particle $A$, which then decays into particle $B+C$, then I can find the total cross-section $pp \to A \to B+C+Y$ ($Y$ being inclusive particle which should be integrated over), by $\sigma_{pp\to A\to B+C} = \Sigma_X \sigma_{pp \to A+X} \frac{\Gamma_{A\to B+C}}{\Gamma_{A_{total}}}$;

But how do I find differential cross-section in terms of momentum and energy of particles B + C produced?

Say, I want

$E_B \frac{d\sigma_{pp\to A\to B+C+Y}}{d^3p_B dE_C}$;

More precisely, I have calculated something like
$E_B \frac{d\Gamma_{A\to B+C+Y}}{d^3p_B dE_C}$ at the rest frame of the parent particle $A$;

How do I use this information and production rate of particle $A$ from $pp-$beam, to get what I want?